error 404 Not Found nginx wp-admin is showing an error
The site is working. But wp-admin is showing an error. Error defined as error 404 Not Found. What could be the reason for this. If I open wp-admin from site hosting then that wp-admin is opening. But from here wp-admin is not working.
Site : https://modafinilminds.com/wp-admin
I try to check files and try to fixed this issue and update .htaccess page.
My .htaccess Page :

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^en/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ja/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN LiteSpeed
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN LiteSpeed" and "END LiteSpeed" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule Litespeed>
SetEnv noabort 1
</IfModule>
# END LiteSpeed
    

So can anyone tell me what could be the reason for this. And how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

"If I open wp-admin from site hosting then that wp-admin is opening. But from here wp-admin is not working." - can you please clarify, what that actually means? What does "opening it from site hosting" mean, and what is "here"?

"But wp-admin is showing an error." - looks like not /wp-admin itself is; accessing the above URL, I am getting redirected to /en/wp-login.php?redirect_to=..., so that is what you actually have a problem with here.

@CBroe Thanks For Answer, i Explain You.
My site is working fine. But there is a problem with the admin panel. In WordPress, the admin panel opens from sitename.com/wp-admin. And if you want to do it from hosting, then you can directly go to the admin panel from there. This option is available in all hostings.
Now the problem is that when I open the admin panel from hosting, it opens. But when I open it from here sitename.com/wp-admin, it is showing 404 error.
I have shown the demo of the error here.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/29019587?key=56784b8c60aa256d3b2750585a620ccb

I still have no idea what you actually mean with "from hosting"
